# How to return base response from Firebase Hosting when accessed via Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, json-ld

I'm trying to drop custom `json+ld` on to my Firebase site.  I'm trying to do this by intercepting ("rewriting") the request to my site using Cloud Functions, getting some `json+ld` information via the Fetch API, then adding that to the content Firebase would normally serve up at the original path.

Is there a way to get the "base" request that Firebase would serve up, and append something to it?

Here's my code:

```
exports.eventJsonLd = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.path == '/') {
        fetch('http://pathtoMyApi?clientIp=' + req.ip).then(resp => {
        if (resp.ok) {
            return resp.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Could not retrieve json+ld');
    })
        .then(x => {

            //*** right here is where I would like to take this script tag 
            //*** and insert it into the body of the normal request to this path

            res.send('<script type="application/ld+json">' + JSON.stringify(x[0]).replace(/typeString/g, '@type').replace(/contextString/g, '@context') + '</script>');

         })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Fetch error: ' + err.message);
            res.status(500).send(err.message);
        });
    }
});
```

Any clues?  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
What about if I were to do something like

```
<script type='application/ld+json' src='http://path-to-my-cloud-function/'></script>
```

?  It's not working for me right now . . . but could something like that be a solution?

Comment: How do you define "base request"?  I'm not sure what you are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Meaning, return the response that normally would have gone to the `'/'` endpoint, but add a piece of json dynamically retrieved from the cloud function.

Comment: If you rewrite hosting URLs to go to Cloud Functions, you have to generate the entire response from within the function.  You can't access the files from hosting from within a function, unless you make a separate HTTP request for one, which doesn't sound like a good thing to do for every request.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. In that case, how do you handle json+ld, served up dynamically on page load? I am trying to figure out how to get dynamically generated content to mix with my standard hosted firebase files.